# How to open camera in WebView in android?

Tags: android, html, webview

I Want to open a camera in Webview but it does not open.

When I try to open image using gallery it working fine but when try to upload image using camera it does not open camera I added all the permission for camera.The step I followed is:

String webViewUrl = "http://www.androidexample.com/media/webview/details.html";

```
    // Javascript inabled on webview  
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // Other webview options
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    //webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    //Other webview settings
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true); 

    //Load url in webview
    webView.loadUrl(webViewUrl);

    // Define Webview manage classes
    startWebView(); 


webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {


        // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType){  

            // Update message
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;

            try{    

                // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard

                File imageStorageDir = new File(
                                       Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                       Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                                       , "AndroidExampleFolder");

                if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                    // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                    imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
                }

                // Create camera captured image file path and name 
                File file = new File(
                                imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_"
                                + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) 
                                + ".jpg");

                mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file); 

                // Camera capture image intent
                final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                                              android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);

                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");

                // Create file chooser intent
                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");

                // Set camera intent to file chooser 
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS
                                       , new Parcelable[] { captureIntent });

                // On select image call onActivityResult method of activity
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

              }
             catch(Exception e){
                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Exception:"+e, 
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }

        }

        // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg){
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
        }

        //openFileChooser for other Android versions
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, 
                                   String acceptType, 
                                   String capture) {

            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
        }



        // The webPage has 2 filechoosers and will send a 
        // console message informing what action to perform, 
        // taking a photo or updating the file

        public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {  

            onConsoleMessage(cm.message(), cm.lineNumber(), cm.sourceId());
            return true;
        }

        public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber, String sourceID) {
            //Log.d("androidruntime", "Show console messages, Used for debugging: " + message);

        }
    });   // End setWebChromeClient

}



// Return here when file selected from camera or from SDcard

@Override 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,  
                                   Intent intent) { 

 if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)  
 {  

        if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
            return;

        }

       Uri result=null;

       try{
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {

                result = null;

            } else {

                // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                result = intent == null ? mCapturedImageURI : intent.getData(); 
            } 
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :"+e,
             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        mUploadMessage = null;

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add permission in your AppManifest like this?

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

You didn't mention it but you will need that added.